# Spring Data JPA findAll(Iterable<ID> ids) doesn't allow duplicated ids

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

So I have a list of Ids

```
List<Integer> ids = [1,1,1,5];
```

And when I pass that list to `findAll(Iterable<ID> ids)`,
instead of returning 4 entities, it will only return 2 with id 1,5.

Is there any way to change findAll() so it wouldn't remove the duplicates?

Comment: Just curious, why don't remove the duplicates from the original list?

Comment: only because I need multiple same entities for some calculation in cases

Comment: Are you sure that the `ids` list it's the representing your PK?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id in (1, 1, 1, 5)` will also return 2 rows, not 4. It's not the repositories job to create cloned objects for you. Just create a [clone method/copy constructor](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/which-is-better-option-cloning-or-copy-constructors.html) if you need to clone the entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild this list after the findAll complete, here is the code:

```
List<Integer> ids = [1,1,1,5];

List<Foo> fooList = fooDao.findAll(ids); // Only two objects

List<Foo> newFooList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Integer id : ids) {
    Foo f; // Find the object from the origin list using `CollectionUtils` etc.

    newFooList.add(f);
}
```